# Why is my vm root being set as app.__vue__?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So, basically, my root vm in Vue is being set to app.__vue__. So for example, if I want to get the router, I would use app.__vue__.$router. Why isn't it just app.$router?

Note that there's a bunch more code to the entire script, I just included  the parts I believe to be relevant.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

var router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {path: '/', component: Dashboard},
        {path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard},
        {path: '/protocol', component: Protocol}
    ]
});
var data = {
    loadPercentage: 0
};
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router: router,
    created: function () {
},
    data: data
});
```

Comment: I expect it's not, it's just that your variable `vm` is not accessible to you. The build process will enclose it in a scope. If you want it accessible outside the scope, try `window.vm = ...`.

Comment: That seems to be the case. Is there any way I can change that in the build process or do you have any suggestions of how to best handle having the vm in a global scope?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to get access to it *outside* the scope of your application other than just testing? In any case, exposing it on the window is probably the easiest. All build processes I know enclose your app to avoid polluting the global space.

Comment: It make it easier to manipulate the data in the root vue if you have it in the global scope, i use quite a few components in my app and as far as I have been able to tell there's no real good way of getting the root vue in a component. What I need to do is have a .vue file component where I can modify the data in the root vue so that I can e.g. trigger the navigation bar visibility. Any ideas on how to handle that without putting the root vue in the global scope? Otherwise I thank you for your wisdom and hope you have a great day. :)

Comment: Well sure. The hacky way would be to use `this.$root`. The typical way would be to emit an event from your component and listen for the event in the parent. Vue is props down, events up. Further, the $router object is available in *all* Vue objects. Finally, you could use state management solution (like Vuex) or a simple global state. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components

Comment: Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get route information from `this.$route`
And handle the router by `this.$router`

Something like  `this.$router.push(location)`

Comment: That's not the problem I'm having. The problem is that I can't access it with this.$router. Or app.$router. I have to access it using app.__vue__.$router, which is long and annoying. It seems to be a scoping issue in the build process as suggested by Bert Evans in the comments above.